# how to upload multiple files to a folder and then display that files in datagridview in c# windows application

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

i want to upload files in a folder and then display that files in datagridview

```
 1) upload files to a folder
 2) display that files in datagridview
```

can any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this code in your form class and then extend it as you want:

```
public string Path { get; set; }
private void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var o = new OpenFileDialog();
    o.Multiselect = true;
    if(o.ShowDialog()== System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        o.FileNames.ToList().ForEach(file=>{
            System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(this.Path, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)));
        });
    }

    this.LoadFiles();
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.LoadFiles();
}

private void LoadFiles()
{
    this.Path = @"d:\Test";
    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(this.Path);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = files.Select(file => new { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file), Path = file }).ToList();
}
```

And here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i have combobox and in combo box i have multiple option like 5sec,10sec 20 sec etc , when i select any one option the gridview refresh after that specific time ? @Reza Aghaei?

Comment: @RazimKhan The job will be done using a timer `Tick` event and combobox `SelectedIndexChanged` event. It seems it is off topic here. You can kindly ask this good question in site and inform me to post a complete answer to be useful for other users too :)

Comment: i post a new question here is link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489707/how-to-refresh-a-gridview-by-a-timer-control-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei i have upload files to FTP server , now i want to display that files in my windows application datagridview as above show, how i will do that.?

Comment: @RazimKhan `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` will work for folders and network shared folders, for reading from ftp we should use a different way. You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923193/list-all-files-from-online-ftp-directory-to-a-listview-c-sharp