# How to Refresh a Gridview by a Timer Control in C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a combobox and in the combobox I have multiple options like 5sec, 10sec 20 sec, etc, when I select any one option the gridview refreshes after that specific time. 
   Following is code which load files in datagridview.

```
public string Path { get; set; }
private void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var o = new OpenFileDialog();
    o.Multiselect = true;
    if(o.ShowDialog()== System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        o.FileNames.ToList().ForEach(file=>{
            System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(this.Path, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)));
        });
    }

    this.LoadFiles();
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.LoadFiles();
}

private void LoadFiles()
{
    this.Path = @"d:\Test";
    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(this.Path);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = files.Select(file => new { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file), Path = file }).ToList();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Put a `Timer` on your `Form`
2. Add 5, 10, 20 to your `ComboBox` and set its `DropDownStyle` property  to `DropDownList`
3. Handle `Load` event of `Form`
4. Handle `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `ComboBox`
5. Handle `Tick` event of `Timer`

Write Codes:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Setting 0 as selected index, makes SelectedIndexChanged fire
    //And there we load data and enable time to do this, every 5 seconds
    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //To load each 5 seconds
}

private void LoadFiles()
{
    //Load Data Here
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Stop();
    this.LoadFiles(); //optional to load data when selected option changed
    this.timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem) * 1000;
    this.timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.LoadFiles();
}
```

Comment: this.timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem) * 1000;
this line give an error ,
 Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: yes its okay now , but its not refresh automatically after 5 sec

Comment: my requirement was there when i select after 5 sec , the its automatically refresh after each 5 sec, its refresh when i select again 5 sec,

Comment: i did the same but , when selected index change event occur it works , after that it not refresh gridview