# Datagridview autoupdate from database everytime open that form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

While adding creating GUI in VS2019 you can add TableDataAdapter which will add/show Datagrid showing that tables data. with this code in designer `this.data1TableAdapter.Fill(this.test1DataSet.data1);`

But problem is if there are any changes in database/table they will not be reflected in that datagrid.
I tried using `data1DataGridView.Update();` and `data1DataGridView.Refresh();` but it literally does nothing. 
than I added my database connection string as datasource.(I know thats stupid attempt, But I tried it anyway.) which obviously didn't worked and erased my whatever(non updated) data showing in datagrid.

So here is my question is there any simple way to update that automatically every time there is change in database/table ?

Disclaimer: I have it working but another way. I will share that too.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Documents\test1.mdb";

OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM data1;", conn);

conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
DataTable ds = new DataTable();

dap.Fill(ds);
data1DataGridView.DataSource = ds;
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Comment: [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) Class (search for it on SO, the MSDN example is not really interesting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me there are two things you can do.

1- create a Refresh button and at that button call the userdefined function refresh

```
public void Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Documents\test1.mdb";
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM data1;", conn);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    dap.Fill(ds);
    data1DataGridView.DataSource = ds;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

}
```

this function rebind data to your new table every time you clicked

2- you can use timer control to refresh your data grid. I am pasting the link [how to use timer control in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489707/how-to-refresh-a-gridview-by-a-timer-control-in-c-sharp-windows-application) you can follow it, and simply paste the above Refresh function definition in timer control. it will refresh your datagrid according to time interval you provide.

Comment: I am already using option 1 and it is working with no problem. But my question is why its not updating on its own but only able to show data of the moment I created that datagrid.option 2 is really not necessary at its updating anyway. But thanks for efforts.

Comment: @HungryCoder think about it this way... your app is requesting data from the database. There is no method to tell a database to send information to one or more apps that may or may not be running on PCs/web servers. The database takes requests, it doesn't broadcast events. It's your app's responsibility to request what it needs from the DB.

Comment: @HardCode thanks for bringing that into my attention.